# Undefined function in mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql, undefined

This page will delete a post:

```
require_once ('db.php');
$db = new DB();
$db->deletePost($_GET['id'], $_GET['postType']);
```

db.php only contains a class which called DB and its functions.

this is a part of db.php:

```
public function deleteComment($post_id, $post_type)
{
    $query = "delete from t_comments where c_type = '$post_type' and c_id = '$post_id';";
    $this->execute($query);
}
public function deletePost($post_id, $post_type)
{
    deleteComment($post_id, $post_type);
    $query = "delete from t_news where n_id = '$post_id';";
    $this->execute($query);
}
```

Then mysql says:
Fatal error: Call to undefined function deletecomment() in db.php on line 70

I defined deleteComment above the deletePost!So what's the problem?Can't I call another function of a class in that class?But in C++, I think it is possible!

Comment: Side note: you better read up on `SQL injection`

Comment: Another side-note, don't use `GET` for your database manipulations; it might cause a search engine or a browser accelerator to wipe out your database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
$this->deleteComment($post_id, $post_type);
```

instead of

```
deleteComment($post_id, $post_type);
```

Comment: thanks a lot! It worked! But why it is required to use $this->... ?does it mean execute the function which is in "THIS" class?

Comment: Because PHP does not know which context to use withou $this, so it will use global scope.In global scope you don't have function with this signature, so it will raise error.

Answer (score 3):

`deleteComment(…` -> `$this->deleteComment(…`

You should give [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) a try mate!